# When my PC is on more networks, how does it select the network to connect to the internet?

Tags: windows

For example:
I have 2 ethernet cards, and one wireless, so I'm connected to 3 networks. But, only the wireless network is connected to the internet. When I try to access it, it doesn't loads (browsers), so how do I change the way to connect?

Comment: Are the Ethernet cards connected to network?

Comment: By your routing table.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the default gateway from the 2 Ethernet cards, and set it properly for the wireless interface. Since only the wireless interface has internet connection, the browser will send the DNS and HTTP packets through it. Check the route table too (type "route print" in cmd), and modify it if needed.

You can find out which interface is used by the browser with WireShark: try to open google.com when you are sniffing on one of the interfaces. If you don't see the HTTP packets, then try to sniff on another interface, and so on, until you find the one used by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question with answer...
[How to select default network interface for internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/403350/how-to-select-default-network-interface-for-internet)

Just set the metrics of the 2 ethernet adapters to 100. It shouldn't affect connecting to devices that are local to those 2 networks though.

Additionally... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779696(v=ws.10).aspx

Alternatively, you can use `route` to set up the table manually... http://blog.palehorse.net/2009/08/24/using-windows-7-with-multiple-gateways-and-dhcp/